# c++11 threads - Operation not permitted exception

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm writing c++11 multi-threaded application.

The main thread is reading from database and puts records in std::queue, threads are taking records from queue and process them.

Application is synchronised using std::mutex, std::condition_variable (defined as class members), methods are using std::unique_lock(class member mutex)

After some time (usually few minutes) - my application crashes with

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Operation not permitted

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff5464700 (LWP 10242)]
0x00007ffff60b3515 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

backtrace from gdb shows:

```
#0  0x00007ffff60b3515 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff60b498b in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff699f765 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.3/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff699d906 in ?? () from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.3/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff699d933 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.3/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff69f0a75 in ?? () from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.3/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007ffff76741a7 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#7  0x00007ffff616a1fd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

How can I get more information about this exception?

I am compiling and linking with -pthread option
G++ 4.8.3 at Gentoo Linux machine
-g option is enabled in both compiler and linker
I tried disabling optimization

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Firstly, please post source code, Secondly: Have you looked at source of stdlib++ to see where it potentially throws that exception from?

Comment: Is std::queue properly guarded with mutex? std::queue not thread safe.

Comment: You can try to run it with `strace` and check the output.